# what's the geometric representation of flipping the diagonals of a matrix? and why is this necessary for the inverse?

Tags: matrices

consider $x = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$

when finding the inverse of the matrix why do we specifically flip the diagonals, and in particular make $b$ and $c$ negative? what does this represent geometrically?

Comment: We do it because it works.

Comment: This is of no importance - geometrical or otherwise. You only do this for 2x2 matrices, because that's what the algorithm for finding the inverse produces for 2x2 matrices.

Comment: See this [MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89069/should-the-formula-for-the-inverse-of-a-2x2-matrix-be-obvious), for a geometric explanation in terms of Iwasawa decomposition.

Comment: The more general $n\times n$ algorithm that $A^{-1} = \frac1{\det A}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}d&-c\\-b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is a manifestation of goes via the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).

Comment: @Arthur Yes, this is exactly Qiaochu Yuan's answer at the MO-post.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Right, I was too busy formatting my `smallmatrix` to see your link.

Comment: @Arthur No problem, I just wanted to support your comment here.

Comment: In terms of the geometry of the matrix (viewed as a 2-dimensional array of numbers), the transpose of the matrix of cofactors is what you get by swapping the diagonal entries and negating the antidiagonal entries. This is useless geometrically and not very useful mnemonically, *except*, if (as I did) you found that what goes on in the $2 \times 2$ case is so bizarre as to fix itself in your memory, and that helps you remember the rule for inverting larger matrices using the transpose of the matrix of cofactors.

Comment: One nice explanation is given in [this video from 3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBsC34PxzoM) about Cramer's rule.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate you guys sending me these resources but I should have mentioned that I just got out of high school and can't seem to understand any of them, pretty much just learning about what a matrix is.

Comment: In this case your question "what does this represent geometrically?" is perhaps too early, and you should first follow matrices and linear algebra of its own. The very first comment seems to be the best answer then, or not?

Comment: yeah in a sense, I don't regret asking though, I will complete linear algebra and see, maybe mess around with it by myself